# Scrolling stuck after interacting with iframe

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox, iframe, scroll

I have a site in which I'm implementing parallax using [skrollr.js](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/).
In that site I'm also integrating Flash objects created by [Storyline](https://community.articulate.com/hubs/storyline), in iframes.

My problems is that after the user interacts with the Storyline in the iframe, when he tries to continue scrolling to the rest of the content, sometimes the page gets stuck and stops scrolling.

This happens only in Firefox (it doesn't happen in Chrome, and surprisingly enough - not in IE11 either).

The only way to "unstick" the scroll is by the user clicking the browser window again. Of course, that's not intuitive to the user, so I'm trying to find a way to emulate that click programmatically.
I thought that maybe the focus gets lost and the mouse click returns it, so I tried returning the focus to the body programmatically, but that doesn't help:

```
setInterval( function () {
    if ( document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "iframe" ) {
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }
}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this problem got solved by changing the `wmode` parameter from `window` to `transparent`.
The way to do that is [as follows](https://community.articulate.com/discussions/articulate-storyline/integrating-storyline-with-parallax#reply-233685):

I can't find where to change wmode to transparent in Storyline, but I found how to change it in the generated files :

1. In the root of the generated directory, find the story.html file.
2. Go to line 134, where the g_strWMode parameter is defined.
3. Change its value from window to transparent.
4. That's it!